# android fragments strange issue blank screen

Tags: android

I am testing basic Fragements stuff, so i created  4 classes , 1 MainActivity, 1 FragmentActivity and 2 Fragments, the idea is that we invoke the FragmentActivity via a button from the MainActivity, which should show then Fragment1 and Fragment2 , as Fragment1 having 30 % of the screen with orrange background and Fragment 2 the 70 % with background blue.There is no error , just when i click the button in the MainActivity , it goes to the FragmentActivity  , but shows white screen with only the textview , but when i go into the .xml file on the FragmentActivity it shows the Orange-Blue screen ?

here is the MainActivity part

```
    buttonFrag2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,StaticFragment.class);
         startActivity(intent); 
                 }

           });
```

then the StaticFragment Class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class StaticFragment extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {


    super.onCreate(bundle);
        }

}
```

and the static_fragment.xml , which as said is shown correctly in the Graphical Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:baselineAligned="false"
>


<fragment

    android:name="com.example.fragment.ListFrag"
    android:id="@+id/listFrag"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    tools:layout="@layout/list_frag" />

<fragment

    android:name="com.example.fragment.DetailFrag"
    android:id="@+id/detailFrag"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".7"
    tools:layout="@layout/detail_frag" />

</LinearLayout>
```

also as an example one of the Fragment classes (they are identical)

```
package com.example.fragment;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ListFrag extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_frag, container, false);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not setting the content view of your new activity.  You may be pushing to StaticFragment Activity, but you don't load the xml of the view.  After the `super.onCreate()` of your StaticFragmentActivity, add `setContentView(R.layout.static_fragment.xml);`

Should fix the issue.

Comment: thats it :), i was taking that from online course , where they didnt use setContentView , but i guess they were passing it in a different way